# How to convert from unicode escape sequence to UTF-8

Tags: utf-8, poco-libraries, unicode-escapes

How can i convert unicode escape sequence to UTF-8.

The sequence are \uXXXX

Is there a functionality in `POCO` for it?

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, only through [JSON Parser](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/9d259ac02f880a486ebef30acc4e5e83d3e87b5f/JSON/testsuite/src/JSONTest.cpp#L1630).